# How to use/evoke to set in computed through methods?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to update data property through computed property and found that it is impossible to set the value but I can use get/set to assign value in data property. Please see my example first.

```
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      color: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isTitle: {
      get () {
        return this.title
      },
      set () {
        console.log('how can I come to this line?')
        this.title = 'update title example'
      }
    },


   isTitle() {
      this.color = 'red'
      return 'update title example'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   this.getAccessToTitle()
  },

  methods: {
    getAccessToTitle () {
      if (isTitle) {
       this.color = 'red'
      }
    },
```

example looks little bit weird but what I wanted to ask is..
when getAccessToTitle() is called through mounted, I assume, isTitle's set() should update the title in data property isn't it? I am not sure how can I use set in computed property when I call isTitle through methods but not template(I saw many examples that use template to call computed like https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed but it is not what I am looking for!)

Thank you

this is what I wanted to do originally. update color in data and return title in isTitle. Tt works but was told that it is bad way to use computed so I added get/set

```
  data () {
    return {
      title: '',
      color: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
   isTitle() {
      this.color = 'red' <--- 
      return 'update title example' <---
    }
  },
  mounted () {
   this.getAccessToTitle()
  },

  methods: {
    getAccessToTitle () {
      if (isTitle) {
       isColor(this.color)
      }
    },
    isColor(val) {
    // do something...
   }
```

Comment: You can invoke the setter by assigning a value to the computed prop: `this.isTitle = 'my new title'`.

Comment: Thank you @tony19 Is there any way I can assign new value to this.title and return this.title at the same time through this.isTitle?

Comment: You shouldn't do side effects in computed getters like `this.color = 'red'`

Comment: @cindy It doesn't look like your use case calls for a computed prop. You're trying to use computed props in a way that they're not really designed for. Why can't you just use the data prop directly?

Comment: @tony19 Thank you for responding. I think I should redo everything and also need to go back to study about computed!